# Filter unique option values with Autocomplete component from Material UI

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, material-ui

I want **Autocomplete** from **Material UI** to list in the drop-down only unique option values from a property of the objects in my list of objects.

In the example below, the drop-down renders a list with the values `['Color1', 'Color2', 'Color1', 'Color2']`, however I want it to render only unique values, like `['Color1', 'Color2']`.

Here is the list of objects:

```js
options = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name1',
        color: 'Color1'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name2',
        color: 'Color2'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name3',
        color: 'Color1'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Name4',
        color: 'Color2'
    },
]
```

And here is the `Autocomplete` complete component:

```js
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    value={initialTasting}
    options={options}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.color}
    filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
    onChange={(e, value) => {setFieldValue('color', value.color)}}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label={'Color'}
            variant='outlined'
            margin='dense'
            fullWidth
        />
    )}
/>
```

I left the rest of the code out, since it's too long. It uses **Formik**, **Yup**, has children components so on.

---

I guess I can achieve the result I'm looking for using the prop `filterOptions`, however, I can't make it. I'm too new to JavaScript..!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about updating your options array like this?..

```
function getUniqueListBy(arr, key) {
    return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
}

const optionsUnique = getUniqueListBy(options, 'color');
```

...and then pass `optionsUnique` to the options parameter from `<Autocomplete />` component

Comment: that's not exactly what was looking for, because i'll to repeat the same process for each field in my form, and i have a lot of them..! but anyway, i think it helps for now. thanks for your suggestion!